# JButton creating with color

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I am trying to create a set of Jbuttons in a panel with color. each with different text and color properties (gotten from an array)

here is my code

```
for(int e = 0;e<game.players.get(0).getHand().size();e++){
    panel.add(new JButton(){{
       setText(game.players.get(0).getHand().get(e).getValue());
       setBackground(game.players.get(0).getHand().get(e).getColor());
    }});
}
```

But I get an error. It says I cannot access variable e because it is not declared final(local access e is accessed from within inner class).

if I do

```
 for(int e = 0;e<game.players.get(0).getHand().size();e++){
   panel.add(new JButton(game.players.get(0).getHand().get(e).getValue()));
 }
```

it works perfectly fine, except there are no colors for the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the `JButton` before adding it to the panel:

```
MyHand myHand = game.players.get(0).getHand();
for (int e=0; e < myHand.size(); e++) {
   JButton button = new JButton(myHand.get(e).getValue());
   button.setBackground(myHand.get(e).getColor());
   panel.add(button);
}
```

From this code `getHand` appears to return an `Iterable` collection. In that case an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) can be used.